# AngularJS: data change in controller is not reflected to view if Controller has eventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iframe, addeventlistener

I am having issues with displaying the correct behavior in UI after adding `eventListener` into the controller. The code looks like below:

**Controller:**

```
class Controller {
    constructor($http, globals) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.globals = globals;
        this.steps = ['task1','task2', 'task3'];
        this.stepCounter = 0;
        this.selectedObj;
        this.selectedObjModified = '';
        this.selectedObjDataModified = {};
        this.eventId = '';
        this.selectEnabled = true;
    }

    task1(event) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('image-search');

        if (typeof iframe !== 'undefined' && iframe !== null) {
            this.eventId = event.target.id;
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('someMessage', "*")
        }
        else {
            console.error('iframe elementr not found');
        }
        //this eventListener should be active only if message is received from anglerfish

        if(this.eventId == 'select-button') {
            console.log("inside eventHandler", this.eventId);
            window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                var data = e.data;
                if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data !== null) {
                    this.selectedObj = data;
                    this.selectedObj.url = data.url;
                    this.stepCounter++;
                } else {
                    this.selectEnabled = true;
                    console.error('image not selected or anglerfish did not return the valid data ', data);
                }
                }.bind(this), false);
                this.selectEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        step() {
            return this.steps[this.stepCounter];
        }

        gotoPreviousStep() {
            this.stepCounter && this.stepCounter--;
            return this.step()
        }

        gotoNextStep() {
            this.stepCounter++;
            return this.step()
        }

        getSelectedObj() {
            return this.selectedObj;
        }

        task3() {
        //do something
    }
}

export default Controller;
```

Part of the body of **mypage.html**:

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.step() == 'task2'">
    <img ng-src="{{ctrl.selectedObj.url}}" />
</div>

<div ng-show="ctrl.step() == 'task3'">
    //do something
</div>
```

**footer:**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" ng-switch="vm.step()">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger text-uppercase" ng-click="$dismiss(true)">{{ 'CLOSE' | translate }}</button>
            <button type="button" id = "select-button" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" data = "select-button" ng-click="ctrl.task1($event)" ng-disabled="!ctrl.selectEnabled"
                    ng-switch-when="task1">{{ 'SELECT' | translate }}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger text-uppercase" ng-click="ctrl.gotoPreviousStep()" ng-hide="ctrl.step() == 'task1'">{{ 'BACK' | translate }}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" ng-click="ctrl.gotoNextStep()" ng-disabled="!vm.getSelectedObj()"
                    ng-switch-default>{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase btn-success"ng-click="vm.task3()"
                    ng-switch-when="task3">{{ 'SAVE' | translate }}</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

The code works as expected if I add one more task into the array element and between `task1` and `task2` and put one more `div` in view. Here, in `task1`, I select an object from the `iframe` window and get the object details. This logic is inside the `task1` function in `Controller` where I have an `eventListener`. So what is happening is when I click select, it's executing `task1` where `eventListener` gets triggered, when this function is working, the control goes back to view. At some point, `eventListener` will be done with its job, in which case, the step would be `task2` for which I have a `div` enabled in view which is not happening.  It just gets stuck on `task1`, i.e., object selection in `iframe` with the `NEXT` button disabled.
But, if I add one more task in between `task1` and `task2`, control returns back to that new task in view and then again click next, then it will show up the `task2` `div`. I am not allowed to post the exact code but did my best to copy and edit the important parts.

Comment: this is angularjs asin version 1 ?

Comment: Yes. V1 and I am new to angular world

Comment: lol its fine...

Comment: I don't quite understand your complete logic but it looks like you have missed something obvious, you need to invoke `$scope.$apply` if you do anything outside of angular context. (In this case, event)

Comment: Not fully agreed with you. As I said in question, if I add one more task between task 1 and task 2, its working properly. The logic is: view has an iframe from which I select an object and click select (as shown in footer), which will trigger task1 function which has eventListener. This will be async so the control directly goes to this.selectEnabled = false; part and the view remains same. When eventListener completes its job, stepCounter will be incremented, means step[this.stepcounter]='task2', view show show the task2 in div that is what I am expecting but not happening

Comment: could you add a working example somewhere?

Comment: Was able to fix it. thanks